# Proof of formula $\sum_{i=1}^n {}_{i+k}P_{k+1} = \sum_{i=1}^n \prod_{j=0}^k (i+j) = \frac{(n+k+1)!}{(n-1)!(k+2)}$

Tags: combinatorics, summation, proof-writing

I want to learn proof of

> $$\sum_{i=1}^n {}_{i+k}P_{k+1} = \sum_{i=1}^n \prod_{j=0}^k (i+j) = \frac{(n+k+1)!}{(n-1)!(k+2)}$$

Can there be found an elementary algebraic proof that does not require high level of math?

I wrote $$\sum_{i=1}^n \prod_{j=0}^k (i+j)=\sum_{i=1}^n \left(i(i+1)(i+2)(i+3)\cdots (i+k) \right)=\sum_{i=1}^n \frac {(i+k)!}{(i-1)!}$$

Did I start right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, great start, now divide both sides by $(k+1)!$ and use the hockey stick identity
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{i=1}^{n} \binom{i+k}{k+1} =\binom{n+k+1}{k+2}.
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: (+1) Would you mind adding a little detail? Please..I don't know much about combinatorics..

Comment: The hockey stick identity is easily proved by induction, then express the binomial coefficients in terms of factorials & do a bit of algebra. Where do you need more detail ?

Comment: I just heard that word  hockey stick identity, so I wanted to ask..

Comment: It refers to the shape the terms make in pascals triangle https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Combinatorial_identity

Comment: Thank you very much.